# Change DateTime format in JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a class called "Data" and it has "Name", "Date" and "Value".
The "Date" Attribute is a DateTime value.

Now I have a `List<Data>` called "DataList" and I use the JsonConvert function on it like:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataList)
```

But now the Date is displayed like this YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm-SS.
Can I somehow Change this format before the JsonConvert is done?

Comment: The format in the JSON string is not the correct, isn't it?

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea. The date format is part of [RFC7493](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3). All libraries emit and expect dates in the ISO8601 format. Anything else just begs for incompatibility bugs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do could be achieved by specifying the format as a parameter to the SerializeObject method.

Something like this:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
JsonSerializerSettings formatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy"
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, formatSettings);
```

See this page for examples on how to do it: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Comment: Yes, this Looks right. But what do I need to put as second parameter to get a format like "DD/MM/YYYY"?

Comment: I guess you could just set your format string to "dd/MM/yyyy"? Or what am I not understanding?

Comment: yeah, I wrote that bevor you edit your post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

This is not answering the question, because it is so bad, it should only be looked into as a last resort.

JSON, while being humanly readable, is an object serialisation standard to be used across systems. If you need to tweak the format, something is wrong.

The serialized date/time format is in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) form. It has been chosen so that every system that complies to that standard can interpreter the string correctly.

Strings like:

> 2018-09-20T09:23:46+00:00

are perfectly readable, causing no ambiguity, and will deserialize correctly by any system which uses the default settings.

Deviation from these kind of standards can give you serious issues while trying to maintain the system, cross device or cross culture.

Comment: I agree with this in general, but I still see cases where you would like to format the timestamp, for example if the resulting json would be used to display the timestamp on an interface.

Comment: It will take < 20 sec to convert the ISO in any readable arbitrary culture format ánd keep it interchangeable with other systems.

Comment: Given you're in control of both ends, sure, but perhaps you're not.

Comment: Okay, I must give you that one ;-) ... but, in that case: at least kick the supplier.